# Can you recover partitions that have been overwritten twice?

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

I had a problematic OS partition (original) that I could not fix. I made a backup 2 months ago and decided to just restore to that older partition since I could not fix it. I had trouble with the backup as well. So I just formatted the drive and created a fresh install.

I now realize that I can fix the problem on the original partition.

I tried testdisk but I could only find the backup partition I installed. Is it still possible to restore the original partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's theoretically possible the original partition has been left intact and all of the new partitions have been writing against the free space in the original partition... it's not very likely.

Trying to recover that entire partition is probably going to give you no end of trouble, and it'll be much easier in the long run just to start from scratch.  You may be able to recover some individual files, but the entire partition is an exceptionally long shot.